# Group data from CSV (D3.js & Chart.js)

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, chart.js

I have a csv file like that:

```
id,Annee,Origine,Pax_Total
1,2014,AJACCIO,27494
2,2019,AJACCIO,57525
3,2014,ANGERS,1724
4,2019,ANGERS,4725
...
```

And I want to group per Origine and have the sum of Pax_Total.
The aim is to create a bar chart with Chart.js.

There is my code:

```
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gflowiz/mapathon/master/DGAC_flux.csv")
.then(makeChart);

function makeChart(ville) {
  
  var sumPaxTotal = d3.rollups(ville, v => d3.sum(v, d => d.Pax_Total), d => d.Origine)
  var villeOrigine =  d3.groups(ville, d => d.Origine)
  
  var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
  var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'horizontalBar',
      option:{
          maintainAspectRatio: true,
          legend: {
              display: false
            }
      },
      data: {
        labels: villeOrigine,
        datasets: [
          {
            data: sumPaxTotal,
            backgroundColor: '#F15F36'
          }
        ]
      }
    });
console.log(sumPaxTotal)
}
```

Here is the console log for sumPaxTotal.

[image]

I think there is an "array" problem and after lot of research, it's not clear for me...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: A bar chart with Origine (in red) in x Axis and a number (in blue) in y Axis.

Comment: What data format do you expect?

Comment: Origine -> String |
sumPaxTotal -> Integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Arrays.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), this could be done as follows:

```
data: {
  labels: sumPaxTotal.map(v => v[0]),
  datasets: [{
    label: 'DGAC-Flux',
    data: sumPaxTotal.map(v => v[1]),
    backgroundColor: '#F15F36'
  }]
}
```

Please take a look at your amended code below:

```js
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gflowiz/mapathon/master/DGAC_flux.csv").then(makeChart);

function makeChart(ville) {
  let sumPaxTotal = d3.rollups(ville, v => d3.sum(v, d => d.Pax_Total), d => d.Origine);
  let chart = new Chart('chart', {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
      labels: sumPaxTotal.map(v => v[0]),
      datasets: [{
        label: 'DGAC-Flux',
        data: sumPaxTotal.map(v => v[1]),
        backgroundColor: '#F15F36'
      }]
    },
    options: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="250"></canvas>
```